# Tabular Environment is Acting Weird

Tags: tables

I have the following table code in my document,

```
    Arranging the information into the data table gives:

    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering  
    \begin{tabular}{c|cc|c|c} \\ %\hline
             & Taco &  Burrito & Relation & Resources \\ \hline
Production & $x$ & $y$ &   &   \\ \hline
Meat & 5 & 2 & $\leq$ & 15*16=240 \\
Cheese & 3 & 6 & $\leq$ & 22.5*16 =360 \\ \hline
Objective: P & \$0.50 & \$0.80 &  &  \\
 \end{tabular}
\caption{Materials Table}
\label{Table 1:}
\end{table}
```

It is acting weird and giving me a messed up table: 
[image]

Can anyone please explain to me how to format the first vertical line so that it is not longer than the others, and also how to get rid of the large space above the table and the end of "gives". Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You have specified that the first row of the table has no visible content and only a cell in the first column, hence the white space and long rule.

```
\\ %\hline
```

remove the `\\`